# Multiple table search then show null if not found

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am using MySQL. I have 2 tables:

```
Kecamatan
id | name | slug | kota_id
1    Kec1   kec1     1
2    Kec2   kec2     1


Kota
id | nameK | slugK
1    Kot1   kot1
2    Kot2   kot2
```

I want to search in those two tables with one query; how to get a result like this?

Let's say I search for `slug` containing `"kot1"`; then the result will be:

```
id | name | slug | nameK | slugK
1     null   null   Kot1    kot1
```

Then when I search for `slug` containing `"kec2"`, the result will be:

```
 id | name | slug | nameK | slugK
 1    Kec2   kec2   null    null
```

Comment: What queries have you tried? What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: how about the 3rd case, when you actually have data shared.

Comment: it doesn't help that your data in the columns are the same between 2 columns (at the row level), so it is a wild guess what you even want. Improve the question

Comment: Are you looking for a FULL OUTER JOIN?  Does MySQL support that?  If not, you probably need a UNION of a LEFT OUTER JOIN and a RIGHT OUTER JOIN (or of two LOJ with the tables in the reverse order between the two).  Your question is not clear yet, not least because you've not described which columns you are joining (you're filtering on Kecmata.slug, but it isn't clear what your joining columns are), and your data doesn't seem to cover the case where there is related data in both tables. Please add a few more rows (maybe 1 or 2 more rows per table) and the expected output, and identify the join.

Comment: @AnidMonsur i already tried left join and cant get null when kota/kec not found...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler can u give me some example please

Comment: Of what?  You need to give us information before we can help you.  I don't understand how to write the SQL to get the results you want because you've not explained how you get those answers from the data you show.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i want search slug from that two tables.. if slug from kota tables only show kota.nameK and kota.slugK and kecamatan.name and kecamatan.slug is null and if slug from kecamatan result from kota tables is null

Comment: Table `Kota` doesn't have a column `slug` — that's part of what's confusing.  `Kota.SlugK` might be related, but it isn't a column called `Slug`.  You have to be precise — very precise — to get the answer you need.  Are you joining `Kecamata.Kota_ID` with `Kota.ID`, or are you also joining `Kecamata.Slug` with `Kota.SlugK`, or is it only the latter join you're using, or something else? You've not said; you've not shown any foreign key relationships. We won't make guesses; you have to tell us this information accurately, up front. Please do not respond in a comment.  Please update the question!